Unable to access my server after pushing to ec2
I have dockerize my server app with nginx and ssl configuration. Below are what I am doing
I use github actions to run my workflow: I have my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml setup below
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /src/viuhealth-api
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .

FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /src/viuhealth-api
COPY --from=builder /src/viuhealth-api .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["npm", "start"]

compose file below
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: ${ECR_IMAGE_URI}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

So during my workflow, I build the image and push it to ECR(Elastic Container Registry) with the following commands
docker-compose build
docker-compose push

I then ssh into my EC2, pull the image, create a template of a new docker-compose.yml that is going to reference the image I just pulled and setup my nginx configurations using jwilder/nginx-proxy
          # Create a placeholder docker-compose.yml if it doesn't exist
          echo "docker-compose.yml not found. Creating a placeholder file..."
          cat <<EOF > docker-compose.yml
          version: '3.8'

          services:
            # Nginx reverse proxy service
            nginx-proxy:
              image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
              container_name: nginx-proxy
              ports:
                - "80:80"      # Expose HTTP for Let's Encrypt verification
                - "443:443"    # Expose HTTPS for SSL
              volumes:
                - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
                - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
                - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
                - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro   # SSL certificates volume
                - /usr/share/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro   # Allow proxy to discover app container
              networks:
                - proxy
              restart: always

            # Let's Encrypt companion to manage SSL certs
            letsencrypt:
              image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
              container_name: nginx-proxy-le
              volumes_from:
                - nginx-proxy
              volumes:
                - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw   # Write access to certificates
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro   # Needed for Let's Encrypt
              restart: always

            # Your app container
            app:
              image: *******.dkr.ecr.****.amazonaws.com/*****:latest
              container_name: viuhealth-api
              environment:
                - VIRTUAL_HOST=****.com        # Replace with your actual domain
                - VIRTUAL_PORT=3001                  # Port where your app listens
                - VIRTUAL_PROTO=https                # Use HTTPS
                - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=****.com    # Domain for Let's Encrypt SSL
                - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=<my-email-here>  # Your email for SSL notifications
              env_file: .env
              networks:
                - proxy
              restart: always

          volumes:
            conf:
            vhost:
            dhparam:
            certs:

          networks:
            proxy:
              external:
                name: nginx-proxy
          EOF

          # Pull latest images and recreate containers
          sudo docker-compose pull
          sudo docker network create nginx-proxy
          docker-compose up -d --force-recreate

my workflow works and all the containers runs on my ec2 but whenever I try to access any andpoint, it gives me 502 Bad Request
Please can anyone help me.

How is nginx configured. How does it routes the traffic to the app?
